# Navigation Service on Another Frame

Tags: c#, wpf, navigationservice

I currently have a program that has a Window containing two frames, one at the top of the screen, similar to a navigation panel where the user can click on different buttons to navigate to areas of the program, which are loaded into the frame below.

The top frame permanently stays the same, i.e. there are buttons saying `Questions`, `Tags` and `Users` for example that do not change. When the user clicks the `Questions` button they should be taken to the relevant area of the program but within the frame below.

The problem with this is that because they are within the top frame the `NavigationService` loads the relevant page in the frame at the top, not in the main frame in the centre of the screen.

Is there a way that a button clicked within one frame can cause a different frame to load a different page through the `NavigationService`? Here is a paint example;

[image]

EDIT: To update this question what I originally planned on doing is to have the top frame not in a frame, but in the `window` itself. However because the `window` does not inherit from the `page`, I couldn't use the `NavigationService`.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do navigation in WPF with view-model driven MVVM, you can learn about the differences of view driven and view-model driven in the [slides of Bryan Anderson](http://bryanmitchellanderson.com/wp-content/2010/10/MVVM%20in%20the%20Real%20World.pptx).

Then you can switch view-model property instances and let them render with different data templates. A nice way to register data templates from code is shown in this [codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/444371/Creating-WPF-Data-Templates-in-Code-The-Right-Way).

This way the navigation service would change the view-model instances and that's all he has to do. As the type of the instance changes another data template is piked to render the view.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load relevant page  in main frame, you need use the `NavigationService` of the main frame and you can put the top frame  in the `window` itself without in a frame. For example:

In your XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WPF.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" Title="MainWindow" Width="525" Height="350" mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="80" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="Questions" Margin="20" Click="Questions_Click">Questions</Button>
            <Button x:Name="Tags" Grid.Column="1" Margin="20" Click="Tags_Click">Tags</Button>
            <Button x:Name="Users" Grid.Column="2" Margin="20" Click="Users_Click">Users</Button>
        </Grid>
        <Frame x:Name="MainFrame" Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And in your code-behind

```
private void Questions_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //The relevant page you want to load
    QuestionsPage questionsPage = new QuestionsPage();
    MainFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(questionsPage);
    //Also you can use Frame.Navigate Method
    //MainFrame.Navigate(questionsPage);
}
```